# Return duplicate values keys from array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to determine the keys of values, that have duplicates from an array.

What I came up with is:

```
$duplicates_keys = array();
$unique = array_unique($in);
$duplicates = array_diff_assoc($in, $unique);
foreach ($in as $key => $val){
    if (in_array($val,$duplicates)){
        $duplicates_keys[]=$key;
    }
}
```

Which works, but that's pretty resource intensive, is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: 'that's pretty resource intensive' really? How have you ascertained that.

Comment: Go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Steve going through the array multiple times?

Comment: Does this array have a few million entries? If not, i fail to see how this can be resource intensive. Looks like premature optimization to me

Comment: @Steve Consider a site with 20 000 daily unique visitors(not actually sure, about that number, but weekly is 180 000 unique), and an array of some 6000 rows, this can be pretty hard on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, i doubt this is a bottleneck. However you can reduce your iterations to once through the array, as follows:

```
$temp=[];
$dup=[];
foreach ($in as $key=>$val) {
    if(isset($temp[$val])){
        $dup[]=$key;
    }else{
        $temp[$val]=0;
    }
}
```

Note that the value is set as an array key in temp, so you can use O(1) `isset` rather than `in_array`, which must search the full array until the value is found.

This is theoretically faster than your example, but you would need to profile it to be sure (as you should have already done to ascertain your current code is slow).

Probably you can do something else that has a far greater impact, like caching or a better database query

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_intersect()` for this.

```
$duplicates_keys = array_intersect($in, $duplicates);
```

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)